# Remove extra value using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

How to remove the extra value from being generated after the transformation.

**Input:**

```
<response status="200">
    <IDList>
        <IDLists>
            <IDSec>
                <IDField>
                    <IDFields>
                        <ID>123456</ID>
                        <IDState>done</IDState>
                    </IDFields>
                    <IDFields>
                        <ID>12345634</ID>
                        <IDState>failed</IDState>
                    </IDFields>
                </IDField>
            </IDSec>
        </IDLists>
        <code>56</code>
        <msg>yet</msg>
    </IDList>
</response>
```

**XSL for transforming it:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="/response/IDList/IDLists/IDSec/IDField/IDFields/ID">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="IDFields">
        <cid>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
            </id>
            <iDState>
                <xsl:value-of select="IDState"/>
            </iDState>  
        </cid>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required output:**

```
<cid>
  <id>123456</id>
  <iDState>done</iDState>
</cid>
<cid>
  <id>12345634</id>
  <iDState>failed</iDState>
</cid>
```

**Generated output after using the above XSL:**

```
<cid>
  <id>123456</id>
  <iDState>done</iDState>
</cid>
<cid>
  <id>12345634</id>
  <iDState>failed</iDState>
</cid>56yet
```

How to remove the extra **56yet** from the output?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="/response/IDList/IDLists/IDSec/IDField/IDFields/ID">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/response/IDList/IDLists/IDSec/IDField/IDFields[ID]"/>
</xsl:template>
```